# Cannot add data to database using pop up extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I am using AJAX modal popup extender as a sub form. I have a page with text boxes, when a user click a button the data from text boxes should be added to the database and popup appear. The problem is that when the button is clicked, pop up appears but nothing is added to database. If i comment the pop up, everything works fine. Please help. Thanx

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewSubmt" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                            ValidationGroup = "NewUser" onclick="btnNewSubmt_Click" OnClientClick = "return isPageValid()"/>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnValidPopUp" runat="server" Text="Button" style = "display:none"/>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlUserWorkShop" runat="server">
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlWorkSName" runat="server" 
                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WildLife_EducationConnectionString %>" 
                                    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [WorkshopName] FROM [tblWorkshop]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Please select work shop you would like to register for:"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWorkShopChose" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="sqlWorkSName" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                                    DataTextField="WorkshopName" DataValueField="WorkshopName">
                                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlUserWorkShop" runat="server" TargetControlID = "btnValidPopUp" PopupControlID = "pnlUserWorkShop" BehaviorID = "myModalPopup" >
                        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Code behind:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MyDataBase;Initial     Catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=True;"))


    SqlCommand CmdSql = new SqlCommand
    ("INSERT INTO [tbluser] ([UserLastName], [UserFirstName], [UserMiddleInitial]) VALUES (@UserFirstName,@UserLastName, @UserFirstName, @UserMiddleInitial)", conn);
    conn.Open();
    CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLastName", txtNewUserLN.Text.ToString());
    CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserFirstName", txtNewUserFN.Text.ToString());
    CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserMiddleInitial", txtNewUserMI.Text.ToString());  
    CmdSql.Connection = conn;
    CmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Is there any kind of error coming..try to see console from firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TargetControlID = "btnValidPopUp"
```

Because of this your button postback is disable so it is not firing on click event.To achive desired result set  TragetControLiD of moddal popup with button thats visbility is false and on click of ur button btnValidPopUp write this

```
mdlUserWorkShop.Show()
```

Comment: Thank you for response. But TargetControl Id is already = the button which is not displayed(btnValidPopUp). Just made OnClick Event and it still does not work...

Comment: on which button click you are adding data to database...
i can not understand what u said above "ust made OnClick Event and it still does not work"

Comment: btnNewSubmt adds data to data source. I added mdlUserWorkShop.Show() to btnValidPopUp OnClickEvent. I also tried to add it to btnNewSubmt OnClick but still does not add anything to database.

Comment: how u can click btnNewSubmit Bcz Its Not iN modalPopup Panel add that button to panel it work

Comment: i have the following Java script  function isPageValid() 
        {
            var validated = Page_ClientValidate('NewUser');
            if (validated)
             {
                var mdlPopup = $find('myModalPopup');
                if (mdlPopup)
                 {
                    mdlPopup.show();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
 It is to allow pop up only if the page passes all validations. btnValidPopUp is part of it. when i click btnNewSubmt pop up appears but is sopose to also add data to data source

Comment: once the popuu open means show than u can not click anything which not in cliuded in ur popup.....unless u hide that popup background items aare disable when popup show up

Comment: { mdlPopup.show(); return false; } remove false from this line it will work or u can return true,,,,if u want

Comment: I totally forgot to check the Java script. It works now. Thank you a lot for your time and help!